# MCTS Handling N player games opponent actions

Tags: tree, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, multiplayer

I would like to know how N player games are handled in MCTS. Are the actions of the opponent embedded in the search tree?
Is their value generated the same way as the other Actions?
If so wouldn't their value change the total value of the parent state in a wrong way?
mcts.ai is a nice helpful site but concerning n-player games. The example code just states "would need extra logic for n-player games"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact it is not as easy, as just modeling few additional players that maximize their own profits.

There have been at least few different approaches to the problem of multi-player games, including:

- `max^n` (the simplest)
- Paranoid
- Best Reply Search (BRS)
- Coalition-Mixer

The main issue in the MCTS based approaches is to find an equlibrium between lighweight simulations/evaluations and knowledge embeeded in them. Multi-player games introduce their own parameters to this complex equation, and as a result - there are some interesting modifications that can find better solution (in terms of limited resources) then naive approaches. One such method is "Playout search", described in detail in [Playout Search for Monte-Carlo Tree Search in
Multi-Player Games](https://dke.maastrichtuniversity.nl/m.winands/documents/acg2011paper.pdf).

The most important difference between 2-player and multi-player games is the fact, that in most of the 2-player games the point system is somehow "symmetric" - if I win, you lose, and vice versa. So, assuming that I want to win, I can think about it as a battle between me trying to win, and my opponent trying to win. Once we introduce the third player it is not as simple anymore. Now, if I win - everything is ok. But two other players does not have to play to win, it is enough for them to make me lose (and either of them wins), which makes a foundation of the *paranoid* strategy - we assume that all players play against us, without caring about who actually wins. This alternates the required model (as they no longer maximize any profit), and is just one of possible scenarios. With `N` players on the board, amount of possible coallitions (and their *mixes*) is enormous.

Comment: So if the other players only try their best to win themselves a simple selection of the best move for them, would suffice right? So in the tree the node corresponding to an opponent Player move would have the minimum expected value we could achieve?

Comment: If we assume, that each player tries to maximize its profit AND also assumes, that each other do so, then we could at each node calculate **maximum** value for that player. Minimum value for **us** is not the same as the maximum value for some other player in multiplayer game

Comment: So it would be like Kudkudak said multiple Values in one tree one for each player in each node. And when we simulate an opponent move we traverse the opponent values and pick the most promising one for him and calculate the resulting value for all other Players?

Comment: yes, it would be the simplest of listed cases which in reality is **rarely** the case. Not only because players can have different aims that actually maximizing profits, but also because they are simply not playing that well, and as a result they may (not intentionally) maximize other values (like the other players profits)

Comment: Hello from the future, @lejlot. I would like some insight into "two other players does not have to play to win". Why can't we assume that every player is playing to win? Can't the AI assume that, given any move it makes, the next player will try to maximize their own reward, just as the AI is currently doing? I'd love it if you could take a look at my answer to this post. What am I missing?

Comment: Well you can't assume that this is other players goal because it does not have to be their goal :) it depends on exact dynamics of the game. You can create games that have this property, that are very much "zero sum" one player wins, everyone else loses. But not all games are like this. And not all strategies are like this either. The goal of solving the game, of finding an optimal strategy is to find a way to play that works **for every opponent**. This includes opponents that conspire against you and sacrifice own win to make sure you lose etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is the same case as with the standard Minimax algorithm. After all MCST is just a way to estimate complete Minimax tree. So you can story as game value vector of N rewards, and each players maximizes his outcome.

Considering the exploration policy, I think theoretically the policy doesn't change, but I might be wrong on that one.

Comment: So you say the nodes would have multiple values, one for every Player?

Comment: The variant I have mentioned is the simplest one (`max^n`) and @lejlot answer is more detailed. In essence yes, and every player is trying simply to maximize his outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm almost a decade late, but I've been wondering the same thing. I've read many, many papers on MCTS (though I'm no scholar) and haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer as to why multiplayer MCTS is such a challenge.

Here's how I'm doing it in my implementation. PLEASE critique my approach. I'm sure I'm missing something, but FWIW it plays a multiplayer game that I created reasonably well.

1. Every time we reach a terminal node, we calculate the reward received (e.g. 1 for win, 0 for draw).
2. This reward value is added to the winning team's total, which is **stored in a dict in the node**.
3. Backpropagate that team's reward to all parent nodes, as per usual MCTS process.
4. When determining a node's best child, the effective reward for each child is **that team's total reward MINUS all other teams' total rewards**.
5. Plug that effective reward value into the normal UCB/UCT/whatever formula you're using.

Step 4 is the key difference from the normal 2-player MCTS algorithm. Basically, each node keeps track of EACH team's total reward in a dict, rather than as single number a la minimax.